# Re-initialize a damaged USB stick without recovering data

Tags: usb-drive

I have a USB stick which seems damaged (see below). When it is mounted (automatically or not), it is in read-only mode. I would like to format (or do whatever action) to get a "new" USB stick, that I can use. I do not try to recover any data.

**Is it possible to *reformat/reinitialize* the USB stick so that it becomes usable again?**

For details on the damages:

- I cannot format it using the standard utility: I get an error message (just saying "there was an error").
- `dosfsck -a /dev/sdb1` returns `Logical sector size is zero.`
- Using the `disks` utility, if I try to remove a partition, or to format, I get a long error message, containing in particular `Warning: /dev/sdb contains GPT signatures, indicating that it has a GPT table.  However, it does not have a valid fake msdos partition table, as it should.`
- Using `gparted`, I get the same kind of error messages. I see one big `unallocated` zone that I cannot allocate. I tried to make a new partition table but got the error `The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.`

Comment: Was this stick formatted with [GPT partition(s)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table)? How big is it? I guess you could zero out the various partition headers using `dd`.

Comment: You can try treating it like any other uninitialized drive. Partition the device (either GPT, MBR or just no partitions), and then call appropriate `mkfs` on each partition (or the entire block device in the last case). If there is no physical damage, just corruption, this should work just fine. You could also zero-out the entire drive with `dd` before this, but it's not necessary and in the case of flash memory, it just causes more wear.

Comment: Is it really a USB stick or is it an adapter? If it is an adapter for microSD, SD, etc... those cards have a switch to lock write on them.

Comment: By the way, if you don't mind about USB's data and the problem is not a switch avoiding writing on the device `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1` should clear MBR. After that partition with your desired partition app.